Search a specific pattern using regex in bigquery
I currently have some strings which contains multiple characters. Within those strings I need to match a pattern of \d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3} and extract the matches. Some of the source fields may contain spaces and some may not.
My code is:
SELECT distinct
    Emp_no,
    IF(length(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Emp_no, r"\d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}")) = 7,
        REGEXP_EXTRACT(Emp_no, r"\d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}"),
        REGEXP_EXTRACT(Emp_no, r"\d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{2}")
    ) AS emp_id
FROM
    `table`
where 
    Emp_no IN (
        'CUSPO1234(-99SM901_6',
        '3500974_14HB502',
        '13982666_16TG254-CONV',
        'EA2654CE19011591P5 - 13AH548 - ASC',
        '308697FR700259 ( 15AE411 - BMA '
    )

My output:



Emp_no
emp_id




CUSPO1234(-99SM901_6
99SM901


EA2654CE19011591P5 - 13AH548 - ASC
54CE190


3500974_14HB502
14HB502


13982666_16TG254-CONV
16TG254


308697FR700259 - 15AE411 - BMA
97FR700



Expected output:



Emp_no
emp_id




CUSPO1234(-99SM901_6
99SM901


EA2654CE19011591P5 - 13AH548 - ASC
13AH548


3500974_14HB502
14HB502


13982666_16TG254-CONV
16TG254


308697FR700259 - 15AE411 - BMA
15AE411



Can someone help me in getting the correct string pattern?

We need to come up with an algorithm and then that is expressed/realized in regex.  Please give some thought to the algorithm.  It may be that you want to detect your NNCCNNN pattern but only AFTER a seqence  of arbitrary length at the start of the line ... something like $(NC)+   I'm also going to suggest that this is a 100% regex puzzle and not BigQuery specific.

Questions: (1). Does the employee ID always start with a digit; (2). Is jt always 7 digits?

This is a combination of BigQuery syntax (because not all flavours of SQL contain this functionality) and a regex issue.
Note: The pattern only works if the required emp_id strings are preceded by -, ( or _, with or without spaces.

Find the first instance of characters -, ( or _ and grab that and
anything after it until the end of the string, using REGEXP_EXTRACT(<source field>,r'[<characters to match>].*').
Wrap (1) with a with function to remove the characters -, (, _ or spaces with a zero-length string, using REGEXP_REPLACE.
Then take the first 7 characters of whatever is left, using LEFT.

WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT 'CUSPO1234(-99SM901_6' AS emp_no
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '3500974_14HB502'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13982666_16TG254-CONV'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EA2654CE19011591P5 - 13AH548 - ASC'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '308697FR700259 ( 15AE411 - BMA '
)
SELECT
    emp_no,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(emp_no, r'[-(\_].*') AS step1,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(emp_no, r'[-(\_].*'),r'[ (\_-]','') AS step2,
    LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(emp_no, r'[-(\_].*'),r'[ (\_-]',''),7) AS emp_id
FROM
    tmp

Result:



emp_no
step1
step2
emp_id




CUSPO1234(-99SM901_6
(-99SM901_6
99SM9016
99SM901


3500974_14HB502
_14HB502
14HB502
14HB502


13982666_16TG254-CONV
_16TG254-CONV
16TG254CONV
16TG254


EA2654CE19011591P5 - 13AH548 - ASC
- 13AH548 - ASC
13AH548ASC
13AH548


308697FR700259 ( 15AE411 - BMA
( 15AE411 - BMA
15AE411BMA
15AE411




your question is not clear and I am answering based on my understanding if something doesn't make sense then let me know I can adjust it accordingly.
Fetching everything i.e in between any non-word or non-digit character

[^a-zA-Z0-9]+ : Matches any non word/non digit character and start the look up search.
([a-zA-Z0-9]+) : Match any word/digit and capture only that information


with main as (

SELECT 'CUSPO1234(-99SM901_6' AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EA2654CE19011591P5 - 13AH548 - ASC'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3500974_14HB502'
UNION ALL
SELECT '13982666_16TG254-CONV'
UNION ALL
SELECT '308697FR700259 - 15AE411 - BMA'
)

select *, regexp_extract(value,r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)') from main






I think the RegExp is the problem, trythis pattern instead:
[^\d](\d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3})

Here's a full example showing it in action at regex101.
This add a rule to only capture your 7 digit ID after a non-digit character, so you won't pickup those first invalid patterns anymore. Just update your REGEXP_EXTRACT patterns to use it.
When a capture group exists in the pattern only the value matching that will be returned:

If the regular expression contains a capturing group ((...)), and there is a match for that capturing group, that match is returned.

